# Problema con COUNT(*) No devuelve datos (PHP Y MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, select

Intento contar la cantidad de facturas en la base de datos:

```
//conexion:
    $con=@mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if(!$con){
        die("imposible conectarse: ".mysqli_error($con));
    }
    if (@mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Conexión falló: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". mysqli_connect_error());
    }
```

//Conexion en este archivo:

```
require_once ("config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
require_once ("config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM 'facturas'";

    if ($result) {
        $result = mysqli_query($con, query); 

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array('MYSQLI_ASSOC'); 
        echo $row['total'];
    } else {
        echo "Sin datos que mostrar";
    }
```

El caso que me sale del if y me dice "sin datos que mostrar".

Comment: con que cargas el $result?

Comment: Lo tenía mal colocado, disculpa la confusión, zeross me ha pasado una corrección

Comment: Prueba como dice @A.Palacio, quítale las comillas a 'facturas'.

Comment: Listo! Lo tengo ya sin '' :D

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Su código debe quedar de estar forma:

- Puedes colocar el nombre de la tabla sin las comillas simples.
- Con
      respecto a `mysqli_fetch_array` debe de tener dos parametros, y
      usted le esta pasando uno y de la manera incorrecta.

Codigo:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM facturas";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query); 

if ($result) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result ,MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
    echo $row['total'];
} else {
    echo "Sin datos que mostrar";
}
```

> Referencia: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Acabo de solucionarlo con este método, muchas gracias también por la referencia

Comment: De nada, excelente día.

Answer (score 3):

La verdad es que tengo php un poco oxidado pero, estás preguntando por $result antes de darle valor. A demás, te faltó el '$' antes de query. Prueba así:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM 'facturas'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query); 

//if ($result) {
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array('MYSQLI_ASSOC'); 
    echo $row['total'];
} else {
    echo "Sin datos que mostrar";
}
```

Comment: Cierto con lo del $result y la falta de $ en query, el caso, que acabo de probar y sigue apareciendo "Sin datos que mostrar"

Comment: Claro el if siempre es false al ser $result null o lo que se le asigne sin estar definida.

Comment: Estoy probando sin el "if" pero tampoco me funciona, no entiendo porque no me cuenta...

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta. Cambié el if utilizando la función mysqli_num_rows() para comprobar si la consulta devuelve al menos una fila.

Comment: Está genial, pensaba probar este modo ahora, sigo sin entender porque me sigue saliendo Sin datos que mostrar, y si tengo registros en la tablaç

Comment: Si antes del if haces un echo mysqli_num_rows($result) debería de pintarte 1 por pantalla, antes de 'Sin datos que mostrar'. ¿Puedes hacer esa prueba y comentar que sucede?

Comment: Pues no me muestra nada :S no muestra nada de nada

Comment: Eso ya es mas lógico. ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir como haces la conexión?

Comment: Listo! Ya esta todo editado! y podrás ver como conecto

Comment: Acabo de solcionarlo con el comentari de abajo de A.Palacio!!